# XCODE: Doesn't conform to UITableViewDataSource - methods are right, {} are right

Tags: ios, xcode

Please help, I'm at my wit's end. I've followed multiple tutorials, read every thread similar to this I can find, and five hours later, I'm still lost and getting the same error: "type ViewController doesn't conform to UITableViewDataSource."

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var proTable: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    proTable.reloadData()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return pcMgr.pros.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Pros")

        cell.textLabel?.text = pcMgr.pros[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){

            pcMgr.pros.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            proTable.reloadData()
        }
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Check your `viewDidLoad` bracket

Comment: You put the functions inside viewDidLoad, move them out and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this , you have used old syntax that to inside `viewDidLoad` function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var proTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        proTable.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Pros")

        cell.textLabel?.text = pcMgr.pros[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return pcMgr.pros.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){
            pcMgr.pros.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            proTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the required `UITableViewDataSource` mehods are not correct.
Try this:

```
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        <#code#>
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        <#code#>
    }
```

Because you have already conformed to the protocol, I would recommend using XCode's auto complete on method declarations. Use escape key to see the method declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the protocol functions in Swift 3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell ;
return cell
}
```

Use these methods outside of viewDidLoad method. These methods should be inside your viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

-Remove the functions from viewDidLoad()

-Mention the array

-Add the function "numberOfSections" to the code

hope this helps!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var proTable: UITableView!
    var pcMgr: Array = [] // Or whatever your array is!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        proTable.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
}
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return pcMgr.pros.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Pros")

        cell.textLabel?.text = pcMgr.pros[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){

            pcMgr.pros.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            proTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```